# OJS SMTPMailer: Could not authenticate, OJS 2.4.8.1 with AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses, ojs

I'm using OJS 2.4.8.1, therefore, I want to use the **AWS SES SMTP Service**, so, I've configured the config file *config.inc.php* as follow:

```
; Use SMTP for sending mail instead of mail()
smtp = On

; SMTP server settings
smtp_server = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
smtp_port = 587

; Force the default envelope sender (if present)
; force_default_envelope_sender = On

; Enable SMTP authentication
; Supported mechanisms: PLAIN, LOGIN, CRAM-MD5, and DIGEST-MD5
smtp_auth = PLAIN
smtp_username = XXXXXXXXXX
smtp_password = XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX

; Allow envelope sender to be specified
; allow_envelope_sender = On
```

After sending a test I can view in *error_log* the following:

```
OJS SMTPMailer: Could not authenticate
```

**NOTES**: the username and password are correct, I tried adding the params with/without quotes, I tried with 25, 465 or 587 ports and nothing works.

Any help is well received.

Comment: Can you add smtp_auth = tls and also wha user name and password are you using ? The username and password are the access and secret key which you need to generate from SES console in AWS by navigating to SMTP settings. These are not normal access and secret keys.

Comment: Thank you. With `tls` I got the following error:  `OJS SMTPMailer: Did not receive expected 250 (2)`. Those credentials are correct, I'm using the same SMTP AWS connection without OJS inside PHP script and works well.